# Install Istio on Oracle OKE : error connection reset

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I got a trial Oracle Cloud and spun up a new Oracle Cloud Cluster. 
Then I installed Istio in it. But the Ingress Setup was not working. I kept getting err_connection_reset message from Chrome when browsing to the ingress.

Besides; the Istio documentation, I tried different ways of installing.

In Azure this was straightforward. But in OKE; I couldn't figure out.

I had tried Istio 1.6.2; 1.6.0 and 1.5.5. I tried starting OKE through the portal and then CLI. Just got superstitious.

Followed different walkthroughs 
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/oci/

https://www.ateam-oracle.com/istio-on-oke

But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally realized it was the Load Balancer spun by Istio Ingress by default blocks internet traffic.

I had to update the security rules to allow internet traffic.

**Add Ingress Rules**

- Source CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0   -
- IP Protocol: TCP
- Destination Port Range:  80
- Click Add Ingress Rules

**Add Egress Rules** -

- Source CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0
- IP Protocol: All Protocols
- Click Add Egress Rules